# how to use if condition for the following case in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with a pyspark dataframe as shown below:

df1:

```
+-----------+-------+------------+----------+
|parsed_date|     id|       count|      date|
+-----------+-------+------------+----------+
| 2018-01-16|1520036|        1277|2018-01-17|            
| 2018-01-14|1516457|         767|2018-01-17|           
| 2018-01-15|1518451|        1074|2018-01-17|          
| 2018-01-24|1536787|        1306|2018-01-27|            
| 2018-01-25|1537211|        1105|2018-01-27|            
| 2018-01-26|1539203|        1100|2018-01-27|      
| 2019-01-03|2325105|        1298|2019-01-16| 
+-----------+-------+------------+----------+
```

I am want to `sum` all the `count` for same `date` :

df2:

```
+----------+----------+
|      date|      sum |
+----------+----------+
|2018-01-17|      3118|      
|2018-01-27|      3511|           
|2019-01-16|      1298|    
+----------+----------+
```

So far I could do the following inside a `for` loop for different `date`:

```
df1_list = []
for d in date_list:
    df1= my_func(df, d)
    
    df1 = df1.withColumn("sum", F.sum("count").over(Window.partitionBy("date")))
  
    df1_list.append(df1)

full_df1 = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df1_list)
```

But now there can be a case when there is a date with no records in df1 (or let's say some date is not there in df1) so I want to add `sum` as zero as shown below:

expected output:

example -> date_list: `2018-01-17`, `2018-01-27`, `2019-01-16`, `2019-01-18`

```
+----------+----------+
|      date|      sum |
+----------+----------+
|2018-01-17|      3118|      
|2018-01-27|      3511|           
|2019-01-16|      1298| 
|2019-01-18|         0|
+----------+----------+
```

How can I use `if` condition (or any other logic) while making new column `sum` to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dataframe from `date_list` and do a left join to `df`, before a group by and sum:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

date_list = ['2018-01-17', '2018-01-27', '2019-01-16', '2019-01-18']
date_df = spark.createDataFrame([[d] for d in date_list], 'date string')

result = (date_df.join(df, 'date', 'left')
                 .fillna(0, 'count')
                 .groupBy('date')
                 .agg(F.sum('count').alias('sum'))
         )

result.show()
+----------+----+
|      date| sum|
+----------+----+
|2018-01-17|3118|
|2019-01-16|1298|
|2018-01-27|3511|
|2019-01-18|   0|
+----------+----+
```

Comment: thank you @mck for looking into it. I missed some information before. apologies for that. Actually I have a list of df which are reduced to single df. will the solution that you provided still fit?

Comment: I think it should work - just reduce the dfs to a single one first, and then apply my code

Comment: it works but I guess the operations are computationally quite expensive. It seems to get stuck. Hopefully, it will work.